Structure and Properties of the Set of Residues A for $p^k≡a\mod (qr)$ Where $p,q,r$ are Primes
Let $A$ be the set of $a$ st $p^k≡a\mod  (q⋅r)$ where $p,q,r$ are primes and $k$ is a positive integer
Is there information about $A$ that I can get, like size, what numbers won't be a part, general info.
Specifically, I'm interested in knowing the relationship between $A$ and $p,q,r$.
Currently I know that $|A|$ is a divisor of the $\operatorname{lcm}(q-1,r-1)$ Any additional information or resources would be appreciated, thanks!
EDIT: An example would be $3^k≡a\mod  (5⋅7)$ taking the first few values of $k$, $3^1≡3\mod  (5⋅7)$
$3^2≡9\mod  (5⋅7)$
$3^3≡27\mod  (5⋅7)$
$3^4≡11\mod  (5⋅7)$
In this manner, $A = \{3,9,27,11,33,29,17,16,13,4,12,1\}$

The quantifiers are not clear. If $p,q,r,k$ are all set, then $a\pmod {qr}$ is determined uniquely.  So I guess you want to vary some of the parameters?

I suggest:  include a fully worked example.

So...$k$ is allowed to vary but $p,q,r$ are fixed?  I suggest editing to say that.

In any case, Assuming $p$ is distinct from $q,r$, you have a cyclic subgroup of the multiplicative group of integers $\pmod {qr}$.  The size of it is the order of $p\pmod {qr}$.

Note that $p$ being prime isn't that important: any integer divisible by neither $q$ nor $r$ would have similar outcomes (and indeed there are plenty of composite integers congruent to $p$ modulo $qr$ which give the exact same answer).
